# Why can "dispute" be both verb and noun, but "refute" only a verb?

Tags: etymology, derivational-morphology, nominalizations, zero-derivation

The word *dispute* be used as a verb or a noun:

1. Do not dispute me on this.
2. The dispute was settled quickly.

However, the word *refute* can be used only as a verb:

3. I shall refute this claim.

The only way to use it as a noun is to add the suffix *‑tation*:

4. That was a weak refutation.

Why is this?

Comment: Presumably we have the two *noun* usages ***dispute*** and ***disputation*** because we find *that* distinction useful more often, whereas such fine distinctions are rarely important in the context of ***refutation*** (which can equally well apply to both the *act / practice* of refuting, and the *substance* of any given rebuttal). But essentially, that's just how English happens to have evolved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a noun (synonymous with **refutation**), but it was never very popular, so it died out. For example:

> We finde no concurrent determination of ages past, and a positive and undeniable refute of these present, the affirmative is mutable.

[Pseudodoxia Epidemica](https://books.google.com/books?id=ym0lfhtc2-sC&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=We%20finde%20no%20concurrent%20determination%20of%20ages%20past,%20and%20a%20positive%20and%20undeniable%20refute%20of%20these%20present,%20the%20affirmative%20is%20mutable.&source=bl&ots=voltIgqpwP&sig=ACfU3U03eekO3oZteV0aVcpjjSZXmJua-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqvdbHlpvgAhVQMd8KHdosDpQQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Don't forget the 1694 citation for [the second version](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161156) of the noun to accompany [the first version](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161155): *Keep the quarrel as clean and unmixt as you can, and this will advantage you much both within, and without, in the peace and firmness of your minds, and in the refute of your enemies.*  And there's also the noun [***refutal***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161152).